# Relation between the symmetric part of a matrix and its Gram matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that $A \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a square matrix. Is there any relationship between its symmetric part $$\frac{A+A^\top}{2}$$ and its Gram matrices $A A^\top$ and $A^\top A$? E.g., the spectral norm, the eigenvalues, etc?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide any context on this question, for example in which situation does this question arises?

Comment: For a starter, $\mathbb C$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$, and in which case $A^T$ corresponds to the complex conjugates of $A$, and then $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ represents the real part, while $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ represents the square of the the complex norm.

Comment: One thing that can be said uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: It holds that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)^2\leqslant n \operatorname{tr}(A^\top A),
$$
and since
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{A+A^\top}{2}\right) = \operatorname{tr}(A)
$$
one obtains
$$
\left|\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{A+A^\top}{2}\right)\right| \leqslant \sqrt{n}\|A\|_F,
$$
where $\|A\|_F$ is the Fobenius norm of $A$. So this gives a bound on the sum of eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^\top)$ in terms of the singular values of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps a lot